# Looking for a point in the right direction - openinging MPEG-2 transport stream with python

Tags: python, opencv, mpeg2-ts

I have a question that feels like it should be simple, but my searches haven’t turned up an answer. Hoping someone can help me narrow down keywords or point me to some documentation.

I have a camera connecting to a computer with an **Ethernet** cable, the output format is **MPEG-2** transform stream. I would like to open this in python and run code on it (for the sake of the example - let’s say display it with some text and a frame counter over it), much like I would usually do with a regular *usb webcam* and *opencv*.

Is this a simple matter of syntax, or am I going to be running into bigger problems? Also what are the professional terms for what I’m trying to do that would redirect my search to something more productive? (I’m very much a beginner, feel free to assume I am missing basic info)